# Uninstall Qgis 2.18.16 Windows 10

Tags: qgis

I wanted to fully uninstall QGIS (previously installed by 
osgeo4w). The problem is that it does not appear on the list of programs to uninstall neither in the control panel>programs and features or in settings>apps & features. What I'm I missing?